# Getting the values in response body but web_reg_save_param is not capturing for some request

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am encountering a problem in Load Runner where I can see the valid response in the Response body in snapshot view of request and approx 50% of times the value is captured in  a variable where correlation is done with web_reg_save_param_ex.

But for the same boundaries in web_reg_save_param the values are not captured in the variable in some of the case:

1. I also checked the boundaries are not changing.
2. Used web_set_max_html_param_len("999999") which is enough to capture response in my case.

What could be the other reason for this? Below are the error received in LR.

```
Action.c(181): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "c_abcdef". Either the specified boundaries were not found in the response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter size of 999999 bytes. The total length of the response is 50472 bytes. You can use "web_set_max_html_param_len" to increase the max parameter size.    [MsgId: MERR-26377]

Action.c(181): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "c_trRef". Either the specified boundaries were not found in the response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter size of 999999 bytes. The total length of the response is 50472 bytes. You can use "web_set_max_html_param_len" to increase the max parameter size.     [MsgId: MERR-26377]
```

Comment: Can you please give a specific example of a response (or the relevant part of it) and the correlation rule that didn't capture it. Thanks.

Comment: Setting aside a megabyte of RAM as your match buffer for each variable has a dramatic impact on the footprint of your virtual user when you go to run enmasse on a load generator.  Think like a performance engineer, what is the minimal working set required to get the job done, not the maximum.